# Positioning widget buttons and Entry boxes better in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok, so I'm using the Tkinter module for Python, and I want to have 5 Entry boxes, each of which will be a variable which combines into a single variable, and is used as the serial key for an automatic installer for Office (among other software, for an install script for a medium-sized office).

None of that is really relevant, except to give you an idea of the content.

I am attempting to put all of the Entry boxes in a small space, preferably one or two columns (I am currently using 4-6 columns, I can check).

Is this possible with Tkinter?

Here's my code so far for this part of the script:

```
Label(app, text="Office Serial Key").grid(row=3, column=0)
entries = ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5"]
colnum = 1
for item in entries:
    item = Entry(app, width=10)
    item.grid(row=3, column=colnum)
    colnum = colnum + 1
```

I want to look more professional/like a Microsoft install.

Comment: it is a little more clean to use `enumerate` instead of incrementing colnum each time through the loop:  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: I don't think there's any layout problem you can't solve with one of Tkinter's three managers, grid, pack and place. They are remarkably flexible (and always makes me wonder why other toolkits have to provide so many different ways to accomplish the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot to get the layout exactly the way you want it.  I think that the way to accomplish something like this is to put your `Label`+`Entry`s into another `Frame`, then when you grid that `Frame`, use the `columnspan` keyword to set how wide it should be with respect to the other widgets in "`app`".

( http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm )

here's a silly example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

for i in range(7):
    tk.Label(root,text='%d'%i,width=12).grid(row=0,column=i)

myframe=tk.Frame(root)

tk.Label(myframe, text="Office Serial Key").grid(row=0, column=0)
entries = ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5"]
for column,item in enumerate(entries,start=1):
    item = tk.Entry(myframe, width=10)
    item.grid(row=0, column=column)

myframe.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=3)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oooh. That's nice, illustrates the columns as well as the fact that they're all not in the columns. Fun. Let me see if I can replicate this in my program.